# Is there a faithful transitive locally finite action of the modular group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, group-actions, modular-group

Is there a faithful transitive action of $G = \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ such that orbits under each $g \in G$ are finite?

Comment: What does "orbits under each $g$" mean?  Do you mean that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for all $g$ the set $\{g^k \cdot n \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is finite?  Is there some reason why you require $G$ to act on $\mathbb{Z}$?  Or would you be happy with an action on any countable set?

Comment: @SamNead I would be happy with an action on any countable set and you got the local finiteness condition correctly.

Comment: The existence of such an action of $G = \text{PSL}_2\mathbb{Z}$ on a countable set (call in $C$) implies the existence of such an action for the rank two free group $G = F_2$, because $\text{PSL}_2 \mathbb{Z}$ has a normal $F_2$ subgroup of index 6. Any finite index normal subgroup $N$ would do. That is, by restricting the action of $\text{PSL}_2\mathbb{Z}$ to the subgroup $N$, and then restricting the action of $N$ to any single orbit $C_0$ of the finitely many orbits of $N$ on $C$, one obtains the desired action of $N$ on $C_0$.

Comment: The action of $N$ on $C_0$ is faithful because, if there were a nontrivial kernel $K$, then $K$ would also be the kernel of the conjugate actions of $N$ on the other orbits of $N$ on $C$, and so $K$ would be in the kernel of the whole action of $G$ on $C$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Do you have an idea of what happens if we take $G = \mathrm{Out}(F_n)$ instead? Even for $n = 3$?

Answer (score 1):

Say that a finitely generated group $G$ has property Z if it acts transitively on an infinite countable set $X$ such that the orbits of each element are finite.

1. If a finite index subgroup $H$ of $G$ has property Z, then $G$ has property Z. Namely, given $H$ acting on $X$, take the action of $G$ on the "induced permutation representation"

$$Y = \coprod_{G/H} gX$$

This is transitive, because the action of $G$ acts transitively on the factors, and then $H \simeq g H g^{-1}$ acts transitively on $gX$ by assumption. Because the action is transitive, to check the orbits of all $g \in G$ are finite, it suffices to check it for a single element $x \in X$. Also, to check that the orbit of any $g \in G$ is finite, it suffices to show that the orbit of some finite power of $g$ is finite. Yet, because $H$ has finite index, a finite power of $g$ lands in $H$, which then has a finite orbit on $x \in X$ by assumption.

2. If a quotient $G/H$ has property Z, then $G$ has property $Z$. Explicitly, if $G/H$ acts on $X$, then there is a corresponding action of $G$ on $X$ which factors through $G/H$.

I claim that $G =\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ has property $Z$. The group $G$ is finitely generated and virtually free, so, by (1), we may reduce to the case when $G$ is a finitely generated free group with at least any given number of generators. By (2), we may then reduce to the case of *any* finitely generated group we like. On the other hand, we may now take $G$ to be any finitely generated infinite (hence countable) group such that the order of any element $g \in G$ is finite, and to take $X = G$ with the tautological left action. Many such groups exist (Burnside groups, Grigorchuk group, Tarski Monsters...)

Comment: Note that I wanted the action to be faithful.